# SQL Server iterative 'sp_droprolemember' execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I'm looking for a way to remove all role assignments for a specified database user. To put it another way, I'd like to drop the user from all roles in the database.

I've looked into the use of 'sp_droprolemember' to remove the user from a single specified role but what I'm looking for is a way to iterate through all database roles and drop the user from each.

Can this be done?

Comment: `sp_droprolemember` has been deprecated for years (since at least 2008). YOu should really be using `ALTER ROLE`, like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-droprolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a dynamic statement. Rather than using a loop, create the full dynamic statement, as that's more efficient. Also, don't use `sp_droprolemember`, as that's been deprecated for years and is due to be removed from SQL Sevrer; use `ALTER ROLE`.

As we don't know the version of SQL Server you're using, I'm using the "old" `FOR XML PATH` solution here, however, `STRING_AGG` would be a shorter and easier to understand query if you have a more recent version:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(r.[name] ) + N' DROP MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(u.[name]) + N';'
                  FROM sys.database_principals u
                       JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON U.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
                       JOIN sys.database_principals r ON drm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
                  WHERE u.name = N'Your Login'
                    AND u.type IN ('U','S')
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'')

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend. Always check its value before running the dynamic statement.
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run
```

Comment: This answer was correct insofar as I was able to generate all required DROP statements; thanks.

Comment: I ran into another issue with this however: execution of the SQL statement 'ALTER ROLE [role_name] DROP MEMBER [user_name] returns an error: 'Unknown object type 'MEMBER' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.' It's frustrating as the statement is structured according  to MSDN documentation and both the database role and user exist in the database..